# C++ Shared pointer points to the wrong address when i use make_shared function from stl

Tags: c++11, templates, dynamic, stl, shared-ptr

So i have a class in which there is a shared_ptr declared as following

```
std :: shared_ptr< T > dyn_arr{ new T[ dyn_arr_max_size ], std :: default_delete< T[] >() };
```

This points to the dynamic array of some size. 
I also implemented an iterator for it. Inside this iterator there is a ++ overloaded operator. Now when i get

```
shared_ptr<T> ptr_iter= dyn_arr;
```

for example it will work for the first one or two elements. After that it does not iterate properly. Also i notices the following:

For example my ptr_iter is address ABDC0 for ptr_iter.get() in the beginning
After doing

```
ptr_iter = std :: make_shared<T>( *(ptr.get() + 1 ) );
```

or

```
ptr_iter = std :: make_shared<T>( ptr.get()[1] );
```

`ptr_iter.get()` will point to some other address now like SDBC instead of pointing to ABDC4 for integers for example. Can someone please explain me why is this happening???

I need to be able to do `ptr_iter = make_shared( ptr_iter.get() + 1 );` somehow instead of `ptr_iter = make_shared( *(ptr_iter.get() + 1) );`

Comment: Well, not sure what you're trying to achieve, everything seems a bit weird. However, you will have to post the code for the overloaded operator, if you want us to spot the error.

Comment: Also, `std::make_shared` will allocate new memory and copy the contents of the arguments (the value of `ptr.get()[1]`), so it's no surprise that it points to another memory location.

Comment: @MikevanDyke What i want is to make it not point to the new address but to  the **adress of ptr.get() + 1**
And also my overloaded code is 
**ptr_iter = std :: make_shared<T>( *(ptr.get() + 1 ) );**

Comment: `make_shared` allocates a *new* object at a *new* address. It does not magically make an object held by a `shared_ptr` sharable.

Comment: What is wrong with `ptr_iter = ptr.get() + 1`?

Comment: that way it can not work since they are of different type. Assignment does not work that way

Comment: ptr_iter is also shared pointer type, ptr.get() is of type of normal pointer

Comment: And why do you want to work with `std::shared_ptr` in your iterator? Why not just use `T*` pointers?

Comment: I dont want to, but university assignment says that i have to...Hope you uderstand the situation

Comment: Not sure if you missunderstood your assignment, because it's really bad practice...

Answer (score 0):

`std::make_shared` allocates new memory, which you don't want. To solve this problem just use the constructor of `std::shared_ptr` and pass the adress of the element in the array. However, `std::shared_ptr` attempts to deallocate as soon as the reference count falls to zero, and you will call delete on an element of the array. That's why you'll need to pass a custom delete which does nothing:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> ptr_iter{dyn_arr.get() + 1, [](int* pi) {}};
                                              // ^-- Custom deleter does nothing
```

Example in a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
  std::shared_ptr<int> ptr_iter{dyn_arr.get() + i, [](int* pi) {}};
  std::cout << *ptr_iter.get() << std::endl;
}
```

**However, I strongly recommend to not do this in other cases than in your assignment!**